# Invert latitude of NetCDF in Python / xarray

Tags: python, raster, xarray

I thought it would be straight up, but I don't find a question like this one here.

I created a NetCDF out of a GeoTIFF, but it did not have coordinates or CRS.

I added it doing this:

```
coords = {
'time' : ['2023'],
'y': np.linspace(-90, 90, 1801)[::-1],
'x': np.linspace(-180, 180, 3600),}

b  = xr.DataArray(data, dims=('time', 'y', 'x'), name='test', coords=coords)
b.rio.write_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True)
```

But it does not work. I tried inverting `y` also.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the solution ended up inverting the data itself, doing:

```
np.flipud(data)
```